# PHP SOAP OTA Connection

Tags: php, magento, soap, ota

for a customer I want to implement the OTA service in an interface to check availabilty and things like that.

I've downloaded the 2017 specifications from OpenTravel. But I lack some information. I want to realize it with PHP and SOAP and later connect it to Magento. But I can't find any url for the SOAP client to send those XMLs to.

I would greatly appreciate any help on this topic or maybe suggestions to do it in an easier way.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Consuming  OTA SOAP web services is  tricky as PHP SoapClient class does not handle it properly.

First you should generate the PHP sdk from the WSDL corresponding to the availabilities you need to send requests to. You should give the PackageGenerator project from Github a try.

Nevertheless, as I said, the native PHP SoapClient class does not map the parameters to the XML request correctly. This is where you have to write your proper code to handle the mapping from the PHP objects to the XML request.

As I work regularly on these sorte of issues, I can help you further but only privately at contact@wsdltophp.com.